# MAWK: Store match() in variable

Tags: awk, gawk, mawk

I try to use MAWK where the `match()` built-in function doesn't have a third value for variable:

```
match($1, /9f7fde/) {
  substr($1, RSTART, RLENGTH);
}
```

See [doc](http://invisible-island.net/mawk/manpage/mawk.html#h3-8_-Built-in-functions).

How can I store this output into a variable named `var` when later I want to construct my output like this?

**EDIT2 - Complete example:**

Input file structure:

```
<iframe src="https://vimeo.com/191081157" frameborder="0" height="481" width="608" scrolling="no"></iframe>|Random title|Uploader|fun|tag1,tag2,tag3
<iframe src="https://vimeo.com/212192268" frameborder="0" height="481" width="608" scrolling="no"></iframe>|Random title|Uploader|fun|tag1,tag2,tag3
```

parser.awk:

```
{
  Embed = $1;
  Title = $2;
  User = $3;
  Categories = $4;
  Tags = $5;
}

BEGIN {
  FS="|";
}

# Regexp without pattern matching for testing purposes
match(Embed, /191081157/) {
  Id = substr(Embed, RSTART, RLENGTH);
}

{
  print Id"\t"Title"\t"User"\t"Categories"\t"Tags;
}
```

Expected output:

```
191081157|Random title|Uploader|fun|tag1,tag2,tag3
```

I want to call the `Id` variable outside the `match()` function.

MAWK version:

```
mawk 1.3.4 20160930
Copyright 2008-2015,2016, Thomas E. Dickey
Copyright 1991-1996,2014, Michael D. Brennan

random-funcs:       srandom/random
regex-funcs:        internal
compiled limits:
sprintf buffer      8192
maximum-integer     2147483647
```

Comment: So, what's the expected output? btw, I couldn't find your example search string `9f7fde` in your "input file structure",

Comment: Expected output is the only line that have `191081157` in the first column `$1` or `Embed`. Developing regexp pattern to only return the string after `vimeo.com/` and before `"` is outside of this question's scope. The upper example not work even with the hardcoded string.

Comment: Expected output added.

Comment: You are CALLING match(), not DEFINING match(). The code in the curly brackets is not inside the match() function, it's in an action block that's executed if the match() function returns true. When you do `match($1, /9f7fde/)` then `substr($1, RSTART, RLENGTH)` just contains the string `9f7fde` so that's pretty pointless. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: That string is here for simplicity of the example, later on that will be a regex capture group that will return exactly this part from the urls from every line. I tried to provide the code to the bare minimum problem as near as possible, because someone's job here is to downvote every single question that's not strictly about the problem. I quess only sharing the problem (the part that I thought didn't worked and it) also adding closing flags and downvotes. Either way, you always loose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious answer would seem to be

```
match($1, /9f7fde/) { var = "9f7fde"; }
```

But more general would be:

```
match($1, /9f7fde/) { var = substr($1, RSTART, RLENGTH); }
```

Comment: The second option is work if `print var;` is inside `match()` function. But I want to use this variable outside `match()`. is it possible with MAWK? (With GAWK match() is possible, but because of speed I try to do that with MAWK.)

Comment: @lanti: I have no idea what you mean by "inside" or "outside" match(). Match is a built-in function and everything inside it is part of the implementation. If you mean "inside the action guarded by the match() call," then the variable is certainly usable afterwards, since awk blocks are not scoped. If you mean something else please *edit your question* with a clear example.

Comment: @Lanti: It works here with gawk, mawk, nawk and busybox awk. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Full example provided.

Comment: @Lanti: No, you have not provided any sample input where your code fails

Comment: Sample CSV provided.

Comment: Thank You! With bare minimal example the code it worked. Probably worked on my first try, but I got empty lines, so the problem somewhere in the regex match.

Comment: Probably what tricked me is that I using hardcoded regex string for match (testing purposes), like the numbers in my first code. This way I've got empty strings for `var` in millions of lines... I know, It's late...

Comment: It's completely pointless to do what you are doing with match() and substr().

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE : The solution above mine could be simplified to :

from

```
match($1, /9f7fde/) { var = substr($1, RSTART, RLENGTH) }
```

to

```
{ __=substr($!_,match($!_,"9f7fde"),RLENGTH) }
```

A failed match would have `RLENGTH` auto set to -1, so nothing gets substring'ed out.

But even that is too verbose : since the matching criteria is a constant string, then simply

```
mawk '$(_~_)~_{__=_}' \_='9f7fde'
```

============================================

let's say this line

.....vimeo.com/191081157" frameborder="0" height="481" width="608" scrolling="no">Random title|Uploader|fun|tag1,tag2,tag3

```
{mawk/mawk2/gawk} 'BEGIN { OFS = "";

         FS = "(^.+vimeo[\056]com[\057]|[\042] frameborder.+[\057]iframe[>])" ; 
    
     } (NF < 4) || ($2 !~ /191081157/) { next } ( $1 = $1 )'
```

\056 is the dot ( . ) \057 is forward slash ( / ) and \042 is double straight quote ( " )

if it can't even match at all, move onto next row. otherwise, use the power of the field separator to gobble away all the unneeded parts of the line. The $1 = $1 will collect the prefix and the rest of the HTML tags you don't need.

The assignment operation of $1 = $1 will also return true, providing the input for boolean evaluation for it to print. This way, you don't need either match( ) or substr( ) at all.